# Feynman Lectures on Physics: Vol 1, 11-6: acceleration vector

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, vectors, feynman-diagrams, discrete

I’m trying to get through [11-6 section of Feynman’s Lectures on Physics, Vol 1](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_11.html), particularly explanation of acceleration vector calculation in his example:

> [image: example figures]
>
> [image: example description]

It’s clear that acceleration vector equals `Δv/Δt`, but calculation of its components (tangent and transverse) is obscure to me.

Maybe I’m missing some elementary math or some insight behind working with limits, but:

1. Why tangent acceleration is `dv/dt`?
2. How it even possible to multiply a vector by an angle (`v•Δθ`)?
3. Do I correctly understand that `Δθ/Δt` gives us an angle velocity and transverse acceleration is calculated as product of linear velocity times angular velocity (`v•(Δθ/Δt)`)?

Could someone please explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An acceleration orthogonal to the velocity does not change the speed. For example an object on a circular trajectory with constant speed has only orthogonal acceleration. Therefore the rate of change of speed is the acceleration in tangential direction.
2. $v$ is not a vector, it is the speed. Even if it where a vector, it would just be a multiplication of a vector with some scalar. Remember that an angle in radians is defined by $\theta = s/r$, where $s$ is the arc length of a circle and $r$ the radius. So an angle is just a dimensionless number.
3. Technically yes, but thats not the point. $\Delta v_\perp = v \Delta \theta$ is the same equation as in 2, where $\Delta \theta$ is the angle, $\Delta v_\perp$ the arc length and $v$ the radius of a circle. Of course $\Delta v_\perp$ is a straight line and not a  part of a curved circle, but in the limit of infinitesimally small $\Delta \theta$ the difference disappears, because for a very small angle the curved arc of a circle looks like a straight line.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've found the example to be pretty confusing, as 2 different speeds are used and `r1`, `r2` are used to describe distance from `O`, but approximated circle with radius `R` is used to describe the solution. I would decouple images for better clarity. For example, this image describes tangential acceleration separately pretty well and intuitively obvious: http://bit.ly/Centripetal-Acceleration